# Joomla 1.6 showing blue error message front end "you must login first". Should not be showing

Tags: joomla

Joomla 1.6 showing blue error message front end "you must login first". Should not be showing. Site just went live 2 days ago, and yesterday this error started showing up. Seems like a permissions issue, but everything looks fine. Is there a way to hide the error?

- How would I go about problem solving this error, to see why it is happening?

Click on a few pages, and you will see the error.

- Does not appear when user is logged in.
- Is only happening on 1 compenent

http://www.alumnifootballusa.com/index.php/sign-up-1

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I see it happening on all page, click any link twice.

I think this can be related to some bad extension (module or plugin) that uses `enqueMessage`.

Search for `you must login first` (odd english, will be easy to find). If you find it in language file, search again for that language key.